# Why does the order in a typedef struct/list matter so much?

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault, structure, typedef

I have a structure defined like this:

```
typedef struct ST {
    int line, index, hp;
    char name[4];
    struct ST *next;
} ST;
```

Now, if I let the members in that specific order, I get a segmentation fault in my code. But if I do it like this:

```
typedef struct ST {
    int line, index;
    char name[4];
    int hp;
    struct ST *next;
} ST;
```

I get no more segmentation fault, but it affects some of the result (to be more specific, every list member has 1 "hp" less than it is supposed to).

I have no clue why this happens, can anybody please enlighten me? I've spent more than 5 hours trying to fix the segfault, why does simply swapping two lines fix it all?

Comment: There might be a problem with the other code.

Comment: You are probably writing more than 4 bytes to the variable `name`. The issue isn't the struct, it's some other part of your code. With the second format, when you overwrite the variable `name`, it ends up writing to the int instead of the pointer.

Comment: You have some sort of bug unrelated to this typedef, perhaps an out-of-bounds access to `name`.

Comment: @David I'm 99% sure that I'm not doing that. I'm initialising every member of the list with strcpy(name,"AAAA");

Comment: Well, that's your problem. `strcpy` adds a `NULL` terminating byte after the 4 characters. Always use `strncpy` and specify the length, and increase `name` to be 5, has to contain a `NULL` character at the end.

Comment: @David Oh god, you were right, I forgot of the freaking '\0' character. It works perfectly now. Thanks a lot, I owe you one!!!!

Comment: @David: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; the null character is `\'0'`, sometimes called "NUL". `strncpy` is rarely the right function to use, since it can leave the target array without a terminating `'\0'`; see my rant here: http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html

Comment: @KeithThompson you are right, I always just figured it would copy n-1 and finally append the `NUL` byte. I think I was getting it confused with `snprintf`.